# How change joda--time default DateTime format in Grails

Tags: grails, jodatime, formatting

I am using Grails 2.0.3 (groovy 1.8.6) with joda-time:1.3.1 and joda-time-templates plugins.
Everything works perfectly  but I would like to change displayed format for date and time.
How can I do that? Every domain is scaffolded so I do not have access to any view to render it manually.

My domain

```
import org.joda.time.*
import org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.*

    class Game {

        Team host
        Team guest
        String location
        DateTime date


        static mapping = {
            date type: PersistentDateTimeTZ, {
                column name: "date_timestamp"
                column name: "date_zone"
            }
        }
    }
```

rendered date

```
Date 5/24/12 5:53 PM
```

I would like to get it as

```
Date 5 may 2012 17:53 PM
```

Is there any way to translate name of month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define this in config.groovy

```
jodatime {  format.org.joda.time.DateTime = "dd MMM YYYY HH:mm a" }
```

and that should take care of it.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't realize that this applies specifically to the `<joda:format>` tag.