# Set default joda time duration/period format in Grails

Tags: grails, jodatime

When using [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) with Grails you can set the default [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) format as they have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180431/how-change-joda-time-default-datetime-format-in-grails). I want to do the same thing with [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) and [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) so I don't have to type something like

```
durationFormatter.print(exampleObject.myDuration)
```

every time I want to display a duration or period. I want a call to the `toString()` method of a `Duration` / `Period` object and have it print in the desired format.

I have tried to implement [PeriodFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) in my config file much like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string), but to no avail.  Here is what I have so far in my config file:

```
jodatime {
    format.org.joda.time.LocalDate = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    format.org.joda.time.PeriodFormatter = { new format.org.joda.time.PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendMonths()
        .appendSuffix( " month", " months" )
        .appendWeeks()
        .appendSuffix( " week", " weeks" )
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix( " day", " days" )
        .appendHours()
        .appendSuffix( " hour", " hours" )
        .toFormatter();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had trouble with the default formatter, but then found out that it only applies to the `<joda:format>` tag provided by the Joda-Time grails plugin.  See http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/ref/Tags/format.html.

Answer (score 0):

class

```
ISOPeriodFormat
```

field

```
cStandard
```

this is default period formatter. This field is `private static` and haven't setter. But you can change this value using java-reflection API

```
  final Field f = ISOPeriodFormat.class.getDeclaredField("cStandard");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  f.set(null, yourPeriodFormatter);
```